# is each session call is separate call to server

Tags: php, session

Keeping in mind of server load, I want to know whether each call to session is a separate call to server which increases server load?
Let me explain it little bit. Suppose in each php page, I have to set 10 session data and have to call 10 session data also like this:

```
$_SESSION['a']=1;
$_SESSION['b']=2;
$_SESSION['c']=3;
$_SESSION['d']=4;
$_SESSION['e']=5;
$_SESSION['f']=6;
$_SESSION['g']=7;
$_SESSION['h']=8;
$_SESSION['i']=9;
$_SESSION['j']=10;

echo $_SESSION['a'];
echo $_SESSION['b'];
echo $_SESSION['c'];
echo $_SESSION['d'];
echo $_SESSION['e'];
echo $_SESSION['f'];
echo $_SESSION['g'];
echo $_SESSION['h'];
echo $_SESSION['i'];
echo $_SESSION['j'];
```

setting of above 10 sessions and outputting the same, will these be 20 separate calls to server or by session_start(), whole session data is loaded at once during page loading?

Also want to know how to store multidimensional associative array in session? Suppose I want to set the above 10 session data like this:

```
$_SESSION['mydata']=array(
a=>1,
b=>2,
c=>3,
d=>4,
e=>5,
f=>6,
g=>7,
h=>8,
i=>9,
j=>10
)

echo $_SESSION['mydata']['a'];
```

By the above example I can reduce server loads if each session call is separate call to server.

Anyone clear me what's going on when we set and get session data?

Comment: PHP code is _all_ on the server.

Comment: Do you understand what session data actually is? Data that is persisted between server calls by holding it in a user-specific "session"?

Comment: This does raise one interesting question though... the `$_SESSION` superglobal, is all the data completely propagated when the session is instantiated (holding all the data in memory) OR is there a filesystem read on the session file held in /tmp (by default) whenever $_SESSION is accessed? I'd never actually thought about it before.

Comment: SLaks, I know php is server side code. But I told that as session is itself an associative array, so when we start a session by session_start, whether all stored session loads at once during php script loading or call to each session like $_SESSION['a'] makes a separate call to server?

Comment: @stockBoi - OK, sessions 101. a call to [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) (or statup of the script if sessions are set to autostart) reads data from the session's permanent storage (typically the filesystem) and populates the superglobal $_SESSION. If no session previously existed, an empty $_SESSION is created. A call to [session_write_close()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) or the termination of the script writes the content of $_SESSION to the session's permanent storage... in between, it's held in memory in $_SESSION

Comment: @MarkBaker "in between, it's held in memory in $_SESSION" - cheers, assuages my curiosity too ;)

Comment: Thanks Mark Baker for your clarification. This is the matter I would like to know. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the breakdown of a session

- `session_start();` either creates a session file on the hard drive or accesses one if it is already there. It is a serialized array
- This array gets loaded into memory and is manipulated within memory until the script finishes executing or you can force it to re-write the file with `session_write_close()`

You can add/remove as much data as you wish after you have started the session because it is no different than manipulating an array.

The heavy lifting is done at `session_start` and `session_write_close` because that is when PHP actually has to access the hard drive

In theory each user can have a 4GB session file on a FAT32 server, or larger on NTFS server, but I am sure you can imagine the horrendous performance issues that would arise.

Answer (score 0):

Benchmark for session

For   `$_SESSION['mydata']['key'] = 'value'`  :

```
session_start();
$time_begin = microtime(true);
$mem_start = memory_get_usage();
for ($i=0; $i < 100000; $i++) { 
$_SESSION['mydata']["a$i"] = $i;
}
foreach ($_SESSION['mydata'] as $key => $value) {
    $r = $value;
}
$mem_end = memory_get_usage();
$time_end = microtime(true);
echo "Time :";
echo  $time_end - $time_begin;
echo "<br>";
echo "Memory :";
echo  $mem_end - $mem_start;
```

My result about `$_SESSION['mydata']['key']`:

```
Time :0.57849311828613
Memory :464
```

For `$_SESSION['key'] = 'value'` :

```
<?php

session_start();

$time_begin = microtime(true);
$mem_start = memory_get_usage();
for ($i=0; $i < 100000; $i++) { 
    $_SESSION["a$i"] = $i;
}
for ($i=0; $i < 100000; $i++) { 
    $r = $_SESSION["a$i"];

}
$mem_end = memory_get_usage();
$time_end = microtime(true);
echo "Time :";
echo $time_end - $time_begin;
echo "<br>";
echo "Memory :";
echo $mem_end - $mem_start;
```

My result about `$_SESSION['mydata']`:

```
Time :0.47217416763306
Memory :176
```

EDITED : In the first PHP Script memory spented by the `mydata` array and the other `mydata`'s keys.So, second way is greater again.

So , using `$_SESSION['key'] = 'value'` is greater than `$_SESSION['my']['key'] = 'value'`.

This can be a reason that when you want to set a value to $_SESSION['my']['key'], php should get `$_SESSION['my']` and after that it can be create new var. in the `$_SESSION['my']['key']`

Comment: That fixed the syntax issues, but you failed to answer the OPs question: "Anyone clear me what's going on when we set and get session data?"

Comment: Sorry, it's may bad, I edited my answer based on your question.

Comment: Thanks Dalim for your practical examination. But server load cannot be measured only by execution time. Perhaps a php object executes fast but it uses higher memory of server.

Comment: I added some codes for showing memory usage . Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

The whole execution of your script is done in one request. By setting $_SESSION['foo']='bar' and $_SESSION['baz']='biz' you don't set two different sessions but rather two session *variables*.

So the whole session is loaded on *script start*, not page load (that's a client-side term).

It's all being done with cookies.

**EDIT**, to answer your comment:

As others mentioned (see Mark Baker's comment) the session is loaded once, right before the script kicks off, and stored once after script end (unless you explicitly call `session_write_close()`)

Sure, size matters. Apparently, the bigger the session the longer it will take to be loaded/stored. But that would be the last thing you would bother to optimize.

Comment: Let explain it. Suppose I include two files include('filea.php') and include('fileb.php') in one php page, page01.php. Then when script/page page01.php begins to execute, these two includes will be two separate read operations to server which creates load on server. That's why if we want to reduce on server load, we should reduce includes per php script. That is my concern in respect of session.