# PHP session unset or PHP session destroy

Tags: php, session, authentication, logout

When I'm trying logout with: `session_destroy();` then it worked. But the problem is, I have also a shopping cart with sessions. So `session_destroy();` isn't a option for me. When I'm using the `unset($_SESSION['username']);` function it seems working. But when I go back to my accountpage, I'm just back logged in. My logout script looks like this:

```
<?php
unset($_SESSION['username']);
unset($_SESSION['id']);

header('Location: index?page=home');
?>
```

I checked with this piece of code of a user is logged in. (Can somebody tell me also or this is safe?)

```
<?php if (!$_SESSION['username'] && !$_SESSION['id']){ ?>
<?php header ('Location: index?page=home'); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

This is the info that you need (I think). If you need more, please ask me.

So, my question in the short version: How can I destroy my session without destroying my shopping cart session?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try `session_write_close()` here? There is a PHP configuration which is supposed to automatically do this for you after the script ends but your PHP might be configured differently.

```
<?php
unset($_SESSION['username']);
unset($_SESSION['id']);

session_write_close();

header('Location: index?page=home');
?>
```

For the sake of debugging could you try this:

```
<?php

echo $_SESSION['id'].' - '.$_SESSION['username'];

if(!$_SESSION['username'] && !$_SESSION['id']){
    header ('Location: index?page=home');
}

?>
```

Comment: When I'm using this function it's solved the problem: `session_write_close();` Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome! If you would like to know why this is occurring for you then please read my answer from this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19119354/is-each-session-call-is-separate-call-to-server/19119831#19119831

Answer (score 1):

Might it be possible, that you've just forgot the `session_start();` function call in your logout script?

```
<?php
session_start();

unset($_SESSION['username']);
unset($_SESSION['id']);

header('Location: index?page=home');
```

Comment: I have a session_start(); at the top of my logout script.

Comment: @Appel because actually everything else looks sane… the only I can do is guessing…

Answer (score 0):

in easiest way use

```
<?php
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['user']) && empty($_SESSION['id']))
{
echo "please login";

}
```

and `unset` use to unset the variable and `session_destroy` for destroy session completly, so i suggest you should use both as:

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['user']);
unset($_SESSION['id']);
session_destroy();
header("location:yourpage.com");
?>
```